# What devices work better using indirect bandgap semiconductors?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

In an indirect bandgap semiconductor, a photon must couple to a phonon to be absorbed. This makes the absorption coefficient much lower (and hence solar devices must be thicker), and produces heat in the lattice. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_and_indirect_band_gaps) describes many other disadvantages of using indirect bandgap semiconductors over direct bandgap semiconductors. However, no devices are described in which the indirect gap is used to technological advantage.

Do there exist semiconductor devices which use indirect gaps to technological advantage? Are there cases where all other things being equal, you would prefer to use an indirect gap semiconductor over a direct gap material?

Comment: Possibly this question would be better on Electrical Engineering SE because it concerns the uses and technological exploitation of indirect bandgap materials rather than the physics behind such devices.

Comment: The usual issue is with _emission_, not absorption. Silicon absorbs just fine once a little above band gap - you get to where direct absorption is allowed. On the positive side for indirect materials is that often the free carrier lifetime is longer since it is harder for the carriers to decay directly from the conduction band minimum.

Comment: Indirect gap materials are used in photodiode detectors. There's a full chapter about this in fundamentals of photonics book.